# Cannot import pyodbc via mod_wsgi under Apache on Windows

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyodbc

Versions:

```
Windows 2008 R2 x64
Apache 2.2.19 x86
Python 2.7.3 x86
mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so
pyodbc-3.0.5.win32-py2.7
```

I have verified that Apache works with mod_wsgi calling to Python and have also verified that I can import pyodbc in Python from the command line. But whenever I import pyodbc in a script called from Apache I get these errors in the Apache error log:

```
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3700): Target WSGI script 'C:/Tenor/web/tcwsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3700): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Tenor/web/tcwsgi.py'.
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:/Tenor/web/tcwsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import tcweb
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Tenor\\web\\tcweb.py", line 15, in <module>
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from tc import config, db
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Tenor\\lib\\tc\\db.py", line 6, in <module>
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import pyodbc
[Tue Apr 17 10:26:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried Dependency Walker but it doesn't show any issues (not surprising since I *can* import pyodbc from the Python commandline). I only have one version of Python installed. I have tried running Apache both as a service and from the console under the administrator account.

I have almost an identical setup on another machine, the difference being that it's Windows 2003 Server x86. We are migrating to Windows 2008 R2 and I wanted to test the production web setup and am now stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626807/correct-mt-exe-syntax-to-resolve-pyodbc-import-problems/) and [this post on the pyodbc mailing list](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=214).

You'll need to manually embed the manifest from your Python27.dll into the pyodbc.pyd file due to (if I understand correctly) the binaries being compiled with different versions of the C++ compiler.

The command to do it is mt.exe, and it comes with Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express.